# Is there a way to send static routing data with a parameterized path?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm passing static route data in my route definition like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '/map',
                          component: MapComponent,
                          data: { animation: 'mapPage' } }];
```

Then access it in my component via:

```
constructor(private _contexts: ChildrenOutletContexts) { }

getRouteAnimationData(): Data | unknown {
  return this._contexts.getContext('primary')?.route?.snapshot?.data?.['animation'];
}
```

However, I now also have a parameterized route:

```
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '/record/:type',
                          component: RecordComponent,
                          data: { animation: ':typePage' }
```

Now, of course this will only send the static string `':typePage'` and not, `'areaPage'` or `'languagePage'`, depending on the actual value of `:type`.

Is there a way to get this parameter added to the data value?

Answer (score 0):

i am very unsure that if i gets you correctly ,so pleae elaborate and explain the exact your need in more better .

mean while what you need is use of [ParamMap](https://angular.io/api/router/ParamMap)

```
getRouteAnimationData(): string {
    const type = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('type');
    return type + 'Page';
  }
```

please let me know more on you requirement if i got you wrong

Comment: The `map`-route does not have any query params, so this will result in `'undefinedPage'` instead of `'mapPage'`.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` is meant for static properties only, instead you can go for `state` which is more dynamic, please find below working example demonstrating the usage of state!

child

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ActivatedRoute,
  Data,
  NavigationEnd,
  Router,
  Params,
} from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `<p>
  from state animation! - {{animation}}
  from params! - {{paramValue}}
  </p>`,
  standalone: true,
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  animation: string = '';
  paramValue: string = '';
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.router.events
    //   .pipe(filter((e) => e instanceof NavigationEnd))
    //   .subscribe((e) => {
    //     const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
    //     this.animation =
    //       navigation?.extras?.state?.['animation'] ||
    //       this.activatedRoute.snapshot?.data?.['animation'];
    //   });
    // or

    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
      this.paramValue = params['type'];
      const navigation = this.router.getCurrentNavigation();
      this.animation =
        navigation?.extras?.state?.['animation'] ||
        this.activatedRoute.snapshot?.data?.['animation'];
    });
  }
}
```

parent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import 'zone.js';
import { ChildComponent } from './child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule, ChildComponent],
  template: `
    <a routerLink="/record/helloType" [state]="{animation: 'fromHTML'}">
      navigate to child from html with data 'fromHTML'
    </a> | 
    <a routerLink="/record/asdfType" [state]="{animation: 'fromHTML2'}">
      navigate to child from html with data 'fromHTML2'
    </a>
    <router-outlet/>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter([
      {
        path: 'record/:type',
        component: ChildComponent,
        data: { animation: 'mapPage' },
      },
    ]),
  ],
});
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-rjfvp9?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Well, in theory, it is static. Every route will have its own static animation value, which will never change. I could setup each path on its own, e.g. `{ path: '/record/area', component: RecordComponent, data: { animation: 'areaPage' } }` and it would work but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher Its exactly how you described it, doing like that looks ugly and difficult to maintain, so I am suggesting to use state so that you have the best of both worlds! `data` for static and `state` for dynamic requirements!

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher Also take into account screen reload, if you want it to be usable on screen reload then `queryParams` is your best choice, else `state` and `data` is enough!\

Comment: The issue is, this whole ordeal is about routing animation, which (I'd have to test but I'm fairly certain) will not work with asnchronous operations as the method call `getRouteAnimationData()` will be triggered from the template upon Component construction. Setting the state asynchronously will be too late, the call was already made and the animation didn't trigger, because the value was `undefined`. I need a synchronous solution. I can test it later today, but I'm pretty sure it won't work.

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher then go for queryParams, you can access the configuration syncronously using `this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams.animation` this will solve your issue!

Comment: @OttoAbnormalverbraucher We also have resolver, which will always run before the component loads!

Comment: Btw. I do have a solution looking at the route snapshot itself, but I will add child routes in the future in their own router-outlet, which need their own routing animation, and I fear this will trigger animations when it shouldn't, or won't when it should. Hence, I feel having the data set "statically" in the route itself would be the best option but I would need the route argument resolved for that.

Comment: But queryParams will result in `{ type: 'area' }`, no? It shows the params, not any arbitrary value I assign to the route. And as you can see, I have a `map`-route without any queryParam, so this will not work either.